# To change default map application in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, settings, maps, google-maps

Apple Maps are very inaccurate. They costs my time and money when I use them by accident. 
I want to change the default app to Google Maps.

**How can you change the default Map application in the newest iOS to Google Maps?**

I really would like to delete the Apple Maps from my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of iOS 10 you can delete the iPhone maps application. If you click on a Google Calendar destination, you will then get a message saying the Maps app is missing. Ignore that message. Hold down a finger on the address, select copy, open Google Maps and paste the address you just copied. This saves a few key strokes and it works.

Answer (score 8):

**You can't change the default app.** Some apps give you the option to choose which app to open maps/directions in, but this varies per app and app developer. There is no system toggle and Safari/Siri/etc will continue to open maps in Maps.

Answer (score -2):

Map links from Google Applications in iOS should open in Google Maps: Chrome, Gmail, etc.

Comment: please explain, with details

Comment: In Chrome, if you visit a Google Maps link, it will open in the Google Maps app. This does not, however, change default app registration.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was asking for. The default application is what binds to Contacts, for instance. The problem in iPhone is that you cannot change this thing.

Comment: That is correct, you cannot change the default app across other apps. This Google app affinity is only available amongst their apps.